# Importing flat files in SSIS, error handeling missing delimiters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, delimiter, flat-file

I am importing flat files to a SQL Server DB. I have a for each loop containing a dataflow task which has a flat file source, OLEDB destination and flat file destination for errors. I set the error output settings to redirect rows, I notice one of the flat files has row(s) missing delimiters. Quotes and commas. This is causing it to hang. I've found similar solutions 
but they haven't worked, like setting alwayscheckforrowdelimiter to false.

Thanks!

[image: foreachloop]

[image: data flow task]

[image: error redirection]

[image: row with error]

Comment: You could try sending the error output to a script task instead of a flat file, so that it could handle rows that don't have the expected columns.

Comment: I tried using a custom component, "Delimited File Reader". It worked when I tested it on one file, but when I dynamically set the filename and loop, it can't find the file. I will try to find some sample script code for handling missing " etc.

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using? @Chris

Comment: the one in VS 2010